# Finding Length of Arc

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

[image]

This question looked pretty easy at the start, but I did it in a different method as to what the Answerbook has done. And I couldnt get it right. And the answer in the book gave the correct value but **Why isn't mine giving the right answer?**

> Here is the method used by the answerbook :
>
> Firstly, I know this method even though I used a different one
>
> $$\begin{align}\frac{ds}{dt}= \sqrt{(\frac{dy}{dt})^2+(\frac{dx}{dt})^2}\end{align}$$
>
> And then went onto integrate to find S.

**Here is how I did it:**

$$\begin{align}s= \int_0^2 \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dt\end{align}$$

> $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx}=-\frac{\sqrt{4-t^2}}{\sqrt{t^2+4}}$

$$\begin{align}s= \int_0^2 \sqrt{1+\frac{4-t^2}{t^2+4}}dt=\int_0^2 \sqrt{\frac{8}{t^2+4}}dt\end{align}$$

Substituted $t= 2 tan \theta$

$$\begin{align}s=\int_0^{\pi/4} \sqrt{\frac{8}{4tan^2\theta+4}}2sec^2\theta d\theta\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}{2\sqrt{2}\int_0^{\pi/4}sec\theta d\theta}=2\sqrt{2}[ln (sec\theta+tan\theta)]_0^{\pi/4}\end{align}$$

Which gives :

$=2\sqrt{2}[ln{(\sqrt{2}+1)}-ln{(1)}]$

Which isnt **correct**

Comment: you have to integrate w.r.t $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that
$$dx=t\sqrt{t^2+4}dt$$ and you have to integrate w.r.t $x$

Comment: (Upvoted!) Got it! Thank you. I spent nearly 1 hour trying to figure whats wrong, if not for you I would have to spend more time on this.

Comment: accept it not only only upvote

Answer (score 1):

You haven't applied the length of the curve formula correctly...

Length of the arc is given by

$\int _{l1} ^{l2} \sqrt {1+(dy/dx)^2} dx$

Comment: Got itttttttttttt

Answer (score 0):

You must stay with $$\begin{align}\frac{ds}{dt}= \sqrt{(\frac{dy}{dt})^2+(\frac{dx}{dt})^2}\end{align}$$ Replace the derivatives by their expression and simplify. You should arrive to $$\begin{align}\frac{ds}{dt}=2 \sqrt{2} t dt\end{align}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.